# Entropy change for fusion of ice do not tally from table values

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

In the data book, we have the following entropy values:

- $\mathbf\small{\rm{{S^\circleddash}[H_2O(s)]}}$ = 41 J/(mol K)
- $\mathbf\small{\rm{{S^\circleddash}[H_2O(l)]}}$ = 69.95 J/(mol K)

Wikipedia also gives the same values.
So we get: $\mathbf\small{\rm{{\Delta S^\circleddash}}}$ for fusion of ice = (69.95 - 41) = 29 J/(mol K)
But wikipedia says that: $\mathbf\small{\rm{{\Delta S^\circleddash}}}$ for fusion of ice = 22 J/(mol K)
The wikipedia link is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page)#Thermodynamic_properties 
It is given under the title: Phase behaviour
Please help to identify the mistake.
Thanks

Comment: Either is a mistake or they used different or inconsistent tabulated values in different places.

Comment: The correct value is 22